# rearranging a list of lists so that earlier lists are distributed across later lists

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list:

```
[   [   'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3',
        'col4',
        'some comment',
        'another comment'],
    [   'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3',
        'col4',
        'someone said something',
        'a comment here',
        'more blah blah']
]
```

I'm looking for a more graceful and pythonic way to end up with:

```
[   [  'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'some comment'],  
    [  'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'another comment'] ],
    [  'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'someone said something'],  
    [  'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'a comment here']
    [  'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'more blah blah']
```

than what I've been doing up to now.

- Fortunately, all my inner lists have the same 4 strings (aka, `col1`, `col2`,
  etc).
- I have a ton of inner lists (not just 2).
- There is at least one string that follows the first 4 strings in each inner list; often there are lots.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current list is in a variable called `old_list`:

```
base = old_list[0][:4]
new_list = []

for line in old_list:
    for comment in line[4:]:
        new_list.append(base + [comment])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for loops and slicing:

```
l = [   [   'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3',
        'col4',
        'some comment',
        'another comment'],
    [   'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3',
        'col4',
        'someone said something',
        'a comment here',
        'more blah blah']
]

o = []
for e in l:
    for p in e[4:]:
        o.append(e[:4]+[p])
```

Results in `o` being:

```
[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'some comment'], 
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'another comment'], 
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'someone said something'], 
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'a comment here'], 
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'more blah blah']]
```

The comprehension version of the above loop is:

```
o = [e[:4]+[p] for p in e[4:] for e in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested loop structure is what you desire, which can easily be handled by a nested loop comprehension

```
[inner[0:4] + [rest] for rest in  inner[4:]  for inner in in_lst]
```

The only trick here is to understand the data layout and the intended layout and determine what mapping can achieve it,

namely given

```
[   [   'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3',
        'col4',
        'some comment',
        'another comment'],
    [   'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3',
        'col4',
        'someone said something',
        'a comment here',
        'more blah blah']
]
```

Divided the rows of your input data into two groups

```
[[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], 
  ['some comment', 'another comment']],
 [['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'],
  ['someone said something', 'a comment here', 'more blah blah']]]
```

and loop over all the items in the second group item augmenting with the first group item